# Make Multi-domain with Xampp Server

Tags: php, apache, xampp, subdomain, virtualhost

To make a domain `"abc.ebizbiz.com"` in Xampp, we did like this:

1/ Add one line in the host file

```
    127.0.0.1 abc.ebizbiz.com abc
```

2/ Add these lines in File httpd-vhosts.conf

DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/abc
  ServerName abc.ebizbiz.com

3/ Then Stop and Start Xampp

4/ Input "abc.ebizbiz.com", we can have got a Website

And if we do with other domain "cdef.ebizbiz.com", We do the same step 1,2,3.
But we have got problem with Step 3. If we Stop and Start Xampp, all current Website are running on this Server Xampp will be died.

So, is there any ways to add more thing or make changes with a config file, but don't need Stop and Start Xampp? We are working with a live Server. Many websites are using on it. Can't Stop Server, this process will make all Website died in small time.

Or any solutions to make multi domain the same with above way? Maybe not with Xampp...

Thanks for your support.

Comment: use `reload` instead of `restart`?

Comment: Can you detail more about this. Because we add all these lines by phpCode. You can see our code - shell_exec("/opt/lampp/lampp restart");. And how about code reload Xampp?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set up multiple virtual-hosts then you may find the following article helpful. It is for WAMP. But the procedure may be same for XAMPP.

http://www.codeforest.net/multiple-virtual-hosts-in-wamp

Comment: But when you apply config, you have to Restart Apache server. All Website on this Server have to stop working in a small time. Maybe 5s for it. If we have got 5 task do it. So, it makes problem...How do you think? Thanks

Comment: Are you configuring your local computer or a live server? And which operating system you are using?

Comment: We config it for a live server. And we have got VPS with linux

Comment: Try this and see if it works : http://vpsunmanaged.blogspot.com/2013/05/creating-subdomains-with-apache-virtual.html. Don't forget to reload Apache after setting up your virtual host subdomain (sudo service apache2 reload)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. We got all and make it run well.